# Error when adding a new column to pandas dataframe using a rolling mean function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script where I download some fx rates from the web and would like to calculate the rolling mean. When running the script, I obtain an error in relation to the rates column that I am trying to calculate the rolling mean for. I would like to produce an extra column with the rolling average displayed. Here is what I have so far. The last 3 lines above the comments is where the error seems to be.

Now I get the following error "KeyError: 'rates'"

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url1 = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/'
url2 = 'valet/observations/group/FX_RATES_DAILY/csv?start_date='

start_date = '2017-01-03'  # Earliest start date is 2017-01-03

url = url1 + url2 + start_date  # Complete url to download csv file

# Read in rates for different currencies for a range of dates
rates = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=39, index_col='date')
rates.index = pd.to_datetime(rates.index)  # assures data type to be a datetime

print("The pandas dataframe with the rates ")
print(rates)

# Get number of days & number of currences from shape of rates - returns a tuple in the 
#format (rows, columns)
days, currencies = rates.shape

# Read in the currency codes & strip off extraneous part. Uses url string, skips the first 
#10 rows and returns to the data frame columns of index 0 and 2. It will read n rows according
# to the variable currencies. This was returned in line 19 from a tuple produced by .shape
codes = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=10, usecols=[0,2],
                    nrows=currencies)

#Print out the dataframe read from the web
print("Dataframe with the codes")
print(codes)

#A for loop to goe through the codes dataframe. For each ith row and for the index 1 column, 
# the for loop will split the string with a string 'to Canadian' 
for i in range(currencies):
    codes.iloc[i, 1] = codes.iloc[i, 1].split(' to Canadian')[0]

# Report exchange rates for the most most recent date available

date = rates.index[-1]  # most recent date available
print('\nCurrency values on {0}'.format(date))

#Using a for loop and zip, the values in the code and rate objects are grouped together 
# and then printed to the screen with a new format
for (code, rate) in zip(codes.iloc[:, 1], rates.loc[date]):
    print("{0:20s}  Can$ {1:8.6g}".format(code, rate))

#Assign values into a dataframe/slice rates dataframe
FXAUDCAD_daily = pd.DataFrame(index=['dates'], columns={'dates', 'rates'})

FXAUDCAD_daily = FXAUDCAD

FXAUDCAD_daily['rolling mean'] = FXAUDCAD_daily.loc['rates'].rolling_mean()

print(FXAUDCAD_daily)

#Print the values to the screen
#Calculate the rolling average using the rolling average pandas function
#Create a figure object using matplotlib/pandas
#Plot values on figure on the figure object.
```

New updated code using feedback, I made the following
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

```
url1 = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/'
url2 = 'valet/observations/group/FX_RATES_DAILY/csv?start_date='

start_date = '2017-01-03'  # Earliest start date is 2017-01-03

url = url1 + url2 + start_date  # Complete url to download csv file

# Read in rates for different currencies for a range of dates
rates = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=39, index_col='date')
rates.index = pd.to_datetime(rates.index)  # assures data type to be a     
datetime

#print("The pandas dataframe with the rates ")
#print(rates)

# Get number of days & number of currences from shape of rates - returns     
#a tuple in the 
#format (rows, columns)
days, currencies = rates.shape

# Read in the currency codes & strip off extraneous part. Uses url     
string, skips the first 
#10 rows and returns to the data frame columns of index 0 and 2. It will 
#read n rows according
# to the variable currencies. This was returned in line 19 from a tuple         
#produced by .shape
codes = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=10, usecols=[0,2],
                nrows=currencies)

#Print out the dataframe read from the web
#print("Dataframe with the codes")
#print(codes)

#A for loop to goe through the codes dataframe. For each ith row and for     
#the index 1 column, 
# the for loop will split the string with a string 'to Canadian' 
for i in range(currencies):
    codes.iloc[i, 1] = codes.iloc[i, 1].split(' to Canadian')[0]

# Report exchange rates for the most most recent date available

date = rates.index[-1]  # most recent date available
#print('\nCurrency values on {0}'.format(date))

#Using a for loop and zip, the values in the code and rate objects are     
grouped together 
# and then printed to the screen with a new format
#for (code, rate) in zip(codes.iloc[:, 1], rates.loc[date]):
    #print("{0:20s}  Can$ {1:8.6g}".format(code, rate))  

#Create dataframe with columns of date and raters
#Assign values into a dataframe/slice rates dataframe

FXAUDCAD_daily = pd.DataFrame(index=['date'], columns={'date', 'rates'})
FXAUDCAD_daily = rates['FXAUDCAD']

print(FXAUDCAD_daily)
FXAUDCAD_daily['rolling mean'] = 
FXAUDCAD_daily['rates'].rolling(1).mean()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, when I sliced the original dataframe rates into FXAUDCAD_daily, it already came with the same index of date. So I was getting a key error because the currency abbreviation was used as the name of the column with index 1, not the string 'rate'

But now I have another trivial problem, how do I rename the FXAUDCAD column to just rate. I will post another question for this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

url1 = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/'
url2 = 'valet/observations/group/FX_RATES_DAILY/csv?start_date='

start_date = '2017-01-03'  
url = url1 + url2 + start_date  


rates = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=39, index_col='date')
rates.index = pd.to_datetime(rates.index)  # assures data type to be a     
datetime

print("Print rates to the screen",rates)

#print index
print("Print index to the screen", rates.index)

days, currencies = rates.shape

codes = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=10, usecols=[0,2],
                    nrows=currencies)

for i in range(currencies):
    codes.iloc[i, 1] = codes.iloc[i, 1].split(' to Canadian')[0]

#date = rates.index[-1]  

#Make a series of just the rates of FXAUDCAD
FXAUDCAD_daily = pd.DataFrame(rates['FXAUDCAD'])

#Print FXAUDRATES to the screen
print(FXAUDCAD_daily)

#Calculate the MA using the rolling function with a window size of 1
FXAUDCAD_daily['rolling mean'] =         
FXAUDCAD_daily['FXAUDCAD'].rolling(1).mean()

#print out the new dataframe with calculation
print(FXAUDCAD_daily)

#Rename one of the data frame from FXAUDCAD to Exchange Rate
FXAUDCAD_daily.rename(columns={'rate':'FXAUDCAD'})

#print out the new dataframe with calculation
print(FXAUDCAD_daily)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to fix your code.
First of all, this line seems a bit odd to me, as `FXAUDCAD` isn't defined.

```
FXAUDCAD_daily = FXAUDCAD
```

Then, you might consider rewriting your rolling mean calculation as follows.

```
FXAUDCAD_daily['rolling mean'] = FXAUDCAD_daily['rates'].rolling(WINDOW_SIZE).mean()
```

Comment: I made those change to included  your tips.

Comment: Did you specify WINDOW_SIZE constant? Do you get any additional errors?

Comment: Hi, I tried to change this to 1, but I still get the same key error

Comment: I have even specified the column names as well when I created the rates FXAUDCAD_daily dataframe

Answer (score 0):

What's your pandas version? pd.rolling_mean() is not supported above pandas version 0.18.0

Update your pandas library with:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

And then use rolling() method https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
FXAUDCAD_daily['rolling mean'] = FXAUDCAD_daily['rates'].rolling(*window_size*).mean()
```

Comment: Hi, @Magich, I made those changes, and still no luck

Comment: Oh, I am sorry! I forgot to add that. Here it is below "KeyError: 'rates' "

Comment: @KishanBhatt Look at your code carefully, the error tells you that you don't have 'rates' column in your dataframe FXAUDCAD_daily. Look at this table again and look if there is 'rates' column. If not,  just change its name

Comment: I changed the dataframe assignment to add this column and to set the index='dates'